# How to create new dataframe as a subtruction result from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My df:

```
            items     $
shop_id 
    
10CLV   pen red     5.12
10CLV   pencil red  6.41
10PLB   pen red     7.30
10PLB   pencil red  9.53
```

How to create a new dataframe, where will be one column as a subtruction of two items (only two of them in each shop_id) by each shop_id ?
I mean output:

```
10CLV   -1.29
10PLB   -2.23
```

I can create separate lists, make seaprate subtraction and them put them back as a new dataframe, but maybe there is more elegant way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pivoting values by add `items` to `MultiIndex` with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html), so in next step subtract columns:

```
df1 = df.set_index('items', append=True)['$'].unstack()
print (df1)
items    pen red  pencil red
shop_id                     
10CLV       5.12        6.41
10PLB       7.30        9.53

df = df1['pen red'].sub(df1['pencil red']).reset_index(name='diff')
print (df)
  shop_id  diff
0   10CLV -1.29
1   10PLB -2.23
```

Similar idea with `MultiIndex` - subtract by second level of keys selected by [`Series.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.xs.html):

```
s = df.set_index('items', append=True)['$']
print (s)
shop_id  items     
10CLV    pen red       5.12
         pencil red    6.41
10PLB    pen red       7.30
         pencil red    9.53
Name: $, dtype: float64

df = s.xs('pen red', level=1).sub(s.xs('pencil red', level=1)).reset_index(name='diff')
print (df)
  shop_id  diff
0   10CLV -1.29
1   10PLB -2.23
```

If there are always 2 values per `shop_id` in same position, so possible subtract first and next value per index by:

```
mask = df.index.duplicated()

df = df.loc[~mask, '$'].sub(df.loc[mask, '$']).reset_index(name='diff')
print (df)
  shop_id  diff
0   10CLV -1.29
1   10PLB -2.23
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's only two items by shop-id:

```py
x = df.groupby(level=0)["$"].diff(-1).dropna()
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
shop_id
10CLV   -1.29
10PLB   -2.23
Name: $, dtype: float64
```